# DDD - How to enforce invariants on collections across aggregates

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Let's say we sell cars, customizable cars.

A customer chooses a `CarModel` and then starts configuring the `CarModel`. In our shop, she can only choose the color of the `Steeringwheel`.
Some CarModels can have more types of SteeringWheels than others.

Therefore, we have a `Catalog` which contains `CarModels` and `SteeringWheels`.

A customer can create a `CarConfiguration`. She chooses the model and then from the available steering wheels for that model she chooses the color steering wheel she likes.

```
class Catalog
{
    public IReadonlyCollection<int> CarModels { get; }
    public IReadonlyCollection<int> SteeringWheels { get; }

    public void RemoveSteeringWheel(int steeringWheelId)
    {
        ...
    }
}

class SteeringWheel : AggregateRoot
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Color { get; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

class CarModel : AggregateRoot
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public IReadonlyCollection<int> SteeringWheels { get; }

    public void AddSteeringWheel(int steeringWheelId)
    {
        ...
    }

    public CarOrder CreateCarOrder(int steeringWheelId)
    {
        return new CarOrder(...);
    }
}

class CarOrder : AggregateRoot
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public CarConfiguration CarConfiguration { get; set; }
}

class CarConfiguration : ValueObject
{
    public int CarModelId { get; set; }
    public int SteeringWheelId { get; set; }
}
```

For this to work there is an invariant that the available steering wheels for a car model must always be present in the catalog. To enforce this invariant, we must guard (at least) two methods:

- `AddSteeringWheel` on `CarModel`; we can only add a `SteeringWheel` if it is available in the `Catalog`
- `RemoveSteeringWheel` on `Catalog`; we can only remove a `SteeringWheel` if it is not configured on any `CarModel`.

How to enforce this invariant? CarModel does not know about the SteeringWheel collection on Catalog and Catalog doesn't know anything about CarModel's steering wheels either.

We could introduce a domain service and inject repositories into that. That service would be able to access the data from both aggregates and be able to enforce the invariants.

Other options are to create navigation properties and configure the ORM (Entity Framework Core in my case) to explicitly load those relations.

And probably many more, which I can't think of right now…

What are the most elegant/pure-ddd/best practice options to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

> How to enforce invariants on collections across aggregates

Fundamentally, what you have here is an analysis conflict.  When you distribute information, you give up the ability to enforce a combined invariant.

For example:

> For this to work there is an invariant that the available steering wheels for a car model must always be present in the catalog

So what is supposed to happen when one person is updating a CarConfiguration concurrently with another person modifying the catalog?  What is supposed to happen with all of the existing configurations after the catalog is changed?

In many cases, the answer is "those activities are both to be permitted, and we will clean up the discrepancy later"; ie we'll attempt to detect the problem later, and raise an exception report if we find anything.

(If that answer isn't satisfactory, then you need to go back into your original decision to split the information into multiple aggregates, and review that design).

Pat Helland has a lot of useful material here:

- 2009 [Building on Quicksand](http://www-db.cs.wisc.edu/cidr/cidr2009/Paper_133.pdf)
- 2010 [Memories Guesses and Apologies](https://web.archive.org/web/20100722052618/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pathelland/archive/2007/05/15/memories-guesses-and-apologies.aspx)
- 2015 [Immutability Changes Everything](http://cidrdb.org/cidr2015/Papers/CIDR15_Paper16.pdf)

In effect, your local calculation include stale (and possibly outdated) information from somewhere else, and you encode into your logic your real concerns about that.

Comment: When you say "we will clean up the discrepancy later", do you mean milliseconds later like @DmitriBodiu is saying? Or maybe a lot later when a human operator fixes the problem?

Comment: It could be millis or minutes or months, depending on the cost/benefit analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, it might be that `CarModel` knows something of `SteeringWheels`, as I assume that if you add a `SteeringWheel` with a `Price`, the `Price` of `CarModel` changes?!

So there probably should be a Value Object or Entity as part of the `CarModel` aggregate that represents that.

Furthermore, I think you need a command handler, that knows of both, and decides if the provided `SteeringWheel` is valid, before trying to add that to the `CarModel`, that on its own has to decide if adding the `SteeringWheel` is allowed, trusting the command handler that the reference of the `SteeringWheel` is valid.

Comment: I agree. I'd probably model it as a value object. The method would accept the value object, not an id. The client who calls the method would be responsible to construct the value object given the id. The VO factory could accept a domain service that would retrieve necessary details from the steering wheels model. For deletion, another domain service would be needed.

Comment: Yes, I'm using commands and handlers. And those commands are validated (even against the database). So except for concurrent requests, there won't be an issue. This question is more about those concurrent requests; what if one gets through, how to handle that in the most ddd-like way.

Answer (score 0):

Invariants between aggregates can't be transitionally consistent, only eventually. So when you add a steering wheel to your carModel, you raise an event saying steeringWheelUsedbyCarModelEvent, you catch that event in Domain event handler and update the steering wheel. Steering Wheel aggregate holds an id(or collection if can be used by multiple car configurations) of the carmodel it is assigned to.

Comment: And in the event handler i could throw an exception if the update was breaking the invariants? But then we're enforcing the invariant back at the application layer instead of in the domain. I now see your point that invariants between aggregates can only be eventually. I think... :)

Comment: "And in the event handler i could throw an exception if the update was breaking the invariants?" - why in event handler? event handler calls application layer. App layer calls domain, and then domain checks invariants

Comment: Yea, eventually means, that while event is travelling, (a couple of miliseconds typycally) some other transaction could change state of Aggregate2, which would cause failure of your operation